# Function for Splitting up

Tags: python, function

My instructions were this:

- `def split_up(funds, people)`: Given an  amount  of  money   and a   headcount,  split   up  the funds evenly,   down    to  the penny.
- You  must    use the `%` operator    to  solve   this    one.
- Examples:

  - `split_up(20,3)` → "each  person  (of 3)  gets    $6.67   as  their   share"
  - `split_up(1.5,6)` → "each person  (of 6)  gets    $0.25   as  their   share"
  - `split_up(100,100)` → "each   person  (of 100)    gets    $1.00   as  their   share"

I did this:

```
def split_up(funds, people):
    num1 = funds
    num2 = people
    return "each person (of %d) gets $%.2f/%.2f as their share" % (num2, num1, num2)
```

My problem is when I test it, instead of giving me the calculation of funds/people, it only gives me the numbers for the calculation.  EX: it gives me "200/5" instead of 40.   Can anyone help me here?

P.S. I can not use any import functions.. it needs to just be done the way the instructions say.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I posted what i have tried already.

Comment: It takes input as string so convert it into float. Use as float(200)/float(40).

Comment: You need to calculate the value and print that, e.g. `return "each person (of {0}) gets ${1:.2f} as their share".format(people, float(funds)/people)`. There is really no need to create local bindings (`num1`, `num2`)

Comment: You may use "each person (of %d) gets $%.2f as their share" % (num2, num1/num2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation doesn't do arithmetic, it just puts in directly the values you tell it in exactly those places. Do your calculations first, and only then put it into the string:

```
def split_up(funds, people):
    share = funds / people
    return "each person (of %d) gets $%.2f as their share" % (people, share)
```

Comment: OP didn't make it clear but if they are using Py2 then they will need to cast funds to float() to avoid integer division.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing, but I think your problem is that you are trying to do division within the string. To fix that problem, replace the line with return with this line:

```
    return "each person (of %d) gets $%.2f as their share" % (num2, num1/num2)
```

However, given the information you've told us, I don't think that this alone will be the correct solution to your assignment, although it will run. I would prefer to let you work it out on your own. :P